# How use two structures of xml with the same function

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this

```
<rss>
 <channel>
  <item>
   <link>http://www1</link>
   <title>Doe </title>
   <description>Para  </description>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

and this

```
<feed>
 <article>
   <link>http://www1</link>
   <title>Doe </title>
   <description>Para  </description>
 </article>
</feed>
```

How can I use the same code to work with this two kinds of xml.

I try this but doesn't work

```
$xml_root=$_GET['xml_root'];    // $xml_root='channel'
$xml_item=$_GET['xml_item'];    // $xml_item='item'
$xml= file_get_contents($xmlfile);
$xmldoc = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
foreach ($xmldoc->$xml_root->$xml_item as $xmltree){

I received this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

I try use

foreach ($xmldoc->$xml_root()->$xml_item() as $xmltree){

but doesn't work too
```

Help me Please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `simplexml_load_file`

```
$xmlfile = "rss.xml"; // or feed.xml

$xml= simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);

$array = $xml->channel->item ? $xml->channel->item : $xml->article;

foreach($array as $value) {
    echo $value->link;
}
```

Comment: I received Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in for $array = $xml->channel->item ?: $xml->article;

Comment: Perfect @Bora! Tanks a lot!